# How do I fix: Members (This object from the CMFPlone product is broken!)?

Tags: plone

I have a Plone 2.5 site that when upgraded to Plone 4.1rc3 (or 4.0.x) appears to have a broken Members dir (even if I upgrade to 3.3.x first).

During the course of the upgrade, I get this:

```
2011-06-23 13:44:39 ERROR plone.app.upgrade Upgrade aborted. Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aclark/Downloads/eggs-directory/Products.CMFPlone-4.1rc3-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/MigrationTool.py", line 175, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "/Users/aclark/Downloads/eggs-directory/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/upgrade.py", line 142, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "/Users/aclark/Downloads/eggs-directory/plone.app.upgrade-1.1rc3-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/alphas.py", line 478, in updateLargeFolderType
    update(brain)
  File "/Users/aclark/Downloads/eggs-directory/plone.app.upgrade-1.1rc3-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/alphas.py", line 472, in update
    obj._setPortalTypeName('Folder')
AttributeError: _setPortalTypeName
> /Users/aclark/Downloads/eggs-directory/plone.app.upgrade-1.1rc3-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/alphas.py(472)update()
    471         obj = brain.getObject()
--> 472         obj._setPortalTypeName('Folder')
    473         reindex(obj, idxs=['portal_type', 'Type', 'object_provides'])

ipdb> obj
<persistent broken Products.CMFPlone.LargePloneFolder.LargePloneFolder instance '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07W'>
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't this already by handled by the LargePloneFolder deprecation code? I've never seen this before. I know that at some point there was a code reorganization, with regard to the Products.CMPlone and Plone packages (such that one or the other is now a shim), and I'm wondering if that could be causing a problem.

In the ZMI, the members folder looks like this:

[image]

What can I do to try and investigate/resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your members folder is from the pre-Archetypes days. If I remember correctly the ATContentTypes migrations in early Plone 2.1.x releases did miss large folders at some point.

In Plone 2.5 create a new "Large Plone Folder", make sure it of the correct type (Products.ATContentTypes.content.folder.ATBTreeFolder), move the contents of the Members folder into it, remove the old Members folder and rename the new large folder to Members.

Maybe the ATContentTypes migration code is still there, but I cannot remember anymore at all how to call that. You could also write your own migration code based on Products.contentmigration and run that in the Plone 3.x site.